# Creating custom routes in Rails for SEO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following a tutorial on seo in `rails` and i got my `routes.rb` like this

```
resources :blogs,only: [:new,:index]
get "/blogs/:id", to: redirect("/%{id}")
resources :blogs,:path=>'',except:[:new,:index]
```

everything should be fine but when i create a blog it doesn't show error and doesn't create a blog too.it just redirects to blogs_path.
what am i doing wrong? 
it works fine like

```
resources :blogs
```

but then i would lose the benefits of the other code. and i need them for my `SEO`.

Comment: Post your `new` view code showing how errors are displayed in the form.

Comment: the problem is it doesnt redirect to new wheer it should redirect if its gets an error , thats the way it is designed in controller . and the errors are rendered in _form.html.erb with a helper , the problem is not with rendering errors , I assure you the problem is with routes cause when you change the 2 lines in the question it fixes the problem .
sorry for delay , I live in another Time zone

Answer (score 0):

after a day of sleeping on it I found that i had to mention the :create and :update actions to my routes it'll be like this

```
resources :blogs,only: [:new,:index,:create,:update]
get "/blogs/:id", to: redirect("/%{id}")
resources :blogs,:path=>'',except:[:new,:index]
```